# How do I get a whole row from a Multi-Column PyQT Qtreeview?

Tags: pyqt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I am relatively new to PyQT and I have been researching long and hard and I just cannot find an answer to this question.  Basically what I have is a QTreeView which is populated with data from a QStandardItemModel.  This data has 2 columns and there are various headers that will expand.  When I double click on an item in the Treeview I need to be able to retrieve the whole row that is stored in the QStandardItemModel, but I can only seem to get the single cell that is selected.  I have the following configured right now but it just returns the single cell that is double clicked on

`index = self.treeview.currentIndex()
print index.data().toString()`

I can try to search the model based on the cell that is selected b/c its possible the second column of the listed items could have identical fields, but the first column will always be unique.  I also can't just use the row index as I understand it because the items being selected are children items, so I get an index of 0 for each first child under a parent.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved this by just using a QTreeWidget rather than a QTreeView.  The QTreeWidget allowed me to use the following code to get the first column of the data regardless of which cell was doubleclicked:

`index = self.treewidget.currentItem()
 print index.data(0, 0).toString()`

Comment: I tried to answer the question but I have to wait 24 hours apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by just using a QTreeWidget rather than a QTreeView.  The QTreeWidget allowed me to use the following code to get the first column of the data regardless of which cell was double clicked:

`index = self.treewidget.currentItem()
 print index.data(0, 0).toString()`